# How can I reset windows on a secondary Hard Drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I recently had to send my primary SSD into Samsung to try and get it fixed due to it having issues, and had to start using a slightly older 1TB Hard Drive.  I used the freeware "Macrium Reflect" to copy the OS and all the files onto the Hard drive, but after a few days the Hard Drive refused to boot with a BSOD error of "Bas System Config Info."  Due to this error, I turned to an old 750GB Hard drive and installed an unactivated version of Windows 10 on it.  Just a couple days ago when I tried to boot the 1TB hard drive again, It gave me the error of "Reboot and select proper boot device."  I didn't think this was too much of an error until the Hard Drive didn't show up in Samsung Data Migration as an option to clone.  I tried to use startup tools to fix the errors as well as dskchk.exe, but I couldn't resolve the problem.  I am now wondering if there is any way to use the windows "Reset This PC" setting on my 1TB disk, because it does not work properly.  From what I read on a Microsoft answers board, normally when I go through this process it would say "You have more than 1 disk," but it does not give me that option even though I do have more than 1 disk plugged in.

Comment: You state, " I used the freeware "Macrium Reflect" to copy the OS and all the files onto the Hard drive." By that do you mean you made a *disk image*, which includes all partitions and hidden files, or just copied the files you found?

Comment: I made a disk image.  Sorry for any confusion that may have caused.

Comment: There was ~3GB of data missing after the Image, which I assumed to just be downloaded files that would normally have been saved on onedrive

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you also have a corrupted image. Remove that hard disk and try to do a clean install on another spare hard disk or SSD (if you have one). Copy the files back from the corrupted image if you can.